# Escape URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, escaping, xss

I have a commenting system where people can leave a comment together with their website. Since rails now escapes everything by default I don't really do anything to avoid XSS and it works find - almost. For some reason the URL isn't escaped.

In order to display the username I have a simple helper:

```
def display_name(name, site)
  if !site.blank?
    return link_to(name, site)
  else
    return name
  end
end
```

But if you put something like javascript:alert(1) into the website field it get injected directly into the page - any idea how to escape this?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you escape javascript, malicous users could still create URLs which point to, say, delete urls that could potentially affect a user's data. Why not verify the URL as such when you collect it?

```
validates :attribute, :url => true
```

I'd recommend using Thong Kuah's [UrlValidator](https://gist.github.com/953192).

Comment: Thank you - I guess that's the way it has to be solved. However, could you please help me how I can only perform the validation if the url is not nil (or an empty string)?

Comment: Use this version instead: https://gist.github.com/1051088. Now you call it like `validates :attribute, :url => { :allow_nil => true, :allow_empty => true }`.